# Preventing the concurrent execution of instances fired by a specific trigger

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler

The `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation prevents the concurrent execution of job instances of a specific job, but is it possible to prevent concurrent execution of jobs fired with a specific trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly implement such a restriction with a custom TriggerListener that vetos the job execution and rescheduled the trigger for a later date, or some such.

Otherwise you may just want to make a copy of the job to be fired by your particular trigger.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of Quartz Scheduler, the `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation prevents concurrent execution of job instances based on the unique `JobKey`.

There are no other annotations in the Javadoc that have a similar function for `Triggers`.

Then the only other possibility would be to define a custom `JobKey` - however the class is `final`.

TLDR; No you can't do it without rolling your own synchronisation.